# Override an x:Key of a hosted application from hosting application

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I'm working on an application that is hosted in another application. Both are contained in the same solution, in different projects.

In the hosted application's resource dictionary, I have the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <templates:Template1/>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I'm trying to do is to override the `x:Key` "DefaultTemplate" in the hosting application's `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <views:Template2/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In app `App.xaml` of the hosting application, resource dictionaries are configured as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HostedApplication;component/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HostingApplication;component/HostingResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My expectation was that the hosting application's resource dictionary will override the desired key, but for some reason this doesn't work. I also tried to change the order, and put the hosting application's resource dictionary first.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried to configure my resource as `DynamicResource`, and the following exception was thrown:

```
Additional information: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'DetailTemplate' property of type 'ZoomAndTemplateControlConverter'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

It might be related to the fact that the resource is passed to a property of a converter:

```
<converters:TemplateConverter x:Key="TemplateConverter" 
    Template1="{DynamicResource DefaultTemplate}" 
    Template2="{StaticResource SecondaryTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use DynamicResource to reference DefaultTemplate?

Comment: You must be using {StaticResource DefaultTemplate} somewhere. Replace with {DynamicResource DefaultTemplate} and check if it helps.

Comment: Okay, I tried using `DynamicResource` - an exception is thrown.

Comment: Paste some details on how do you reference those DataTemplates and exception details.